# Modify cell's metadata

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, metadata

I want to store the values of my `IPython.html.widgets` in my ipython notebook somehow.

Is there a way to modify the metadata of the current cell from the code within the cell itself?

Answer (score 5):

I don't know how to do this from within the notebook, but I found a way to do it with a custom [preprocessor](http://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/preprocessors.html) and nbconvert.

You can create a class that extends [nbconvert.preprocessors.ExecutePreprocessor](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/blob/master/nbconvert/preprocessors/execute.py). In the preprocess (or preprocess_cell) method, add logic for storing the relevant output in the cell metadata.

Something like:

```
class MyExecutePreprocessor(ExecutePreprocessor):
    def preprocess_cell(self, cell, resources, index):
        # Execute the cell normally
        cell, resources = super().preprocess_cell(cell, resources, index)
        # Add your magic here
        cell.metadata['widgets'] = {'stuff':'that is cool'}
        return cell, resources
```

You can then execute this preprocessor [programatically](http://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nbconvert_library.html#Using-nbconvert-as-a-library), or as an argument to [nbconvert](http://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#using-as-a-command-line-tool).

Answer (score 3):

If I understand what you are looking for:
from the `Cell Toolbar` (top right of the ipython notebook toolbar), select `Edit Metadata` from the drop-down list.

Comment: That's how you do it manually but I want python code that does this automatically.

Comment: I see; unfortunately no clue.

Answer (score 0):

You can store any execution data by [printing a base64-encoded pickle](https://github.com/jupyter/nbclient/issues/277#issuecomment-1468510451).  When this is run in a [hidden cell](https://jupyterbook.org/en/stable/interactive/hiding.html#remove-an-entire-code-cell), your notebook can define any additional *de facto* metadata accessible via the `NotebookNode` object.  To be explicit, this method differs from @gordon-bean's answer in that it allows you to define the metadata within the notebook's execution and having access to the notebook's variables, rather than in the preprocessor.